# ¿Como pivotear 2 o mas columnas SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo unos queries que me generan 2 tablas temporales, las cuales necesito obtener el total por centro y desglozarlo por instaladas y vendidas.

El primer query, me crea una tabla temporal de las fechas que necesito. Este segundo query me crea las consultas y las guarda en una tabla temporal, con mi tercer query lo que estoy haciendo es tratar de pivotear todos los resultados en una sola, sin embargo, sé que solo se puede pivotear una columna.

Al final del todo, les comparto el resultado que obtengo con mi consulta y les anexo a lo que me gustaría llegar.

```
 ---CALENDARIO
declare @fecha_inicial datetime, @fecha_final datetime, @fecha_actual datetime
declare @total int
set @fecha_inicial = '2017-01-01'
set @fecha_final = '2017-01-30'
set @fecha_actual = @fecha_inicial
set @total = 2
create table #temp_calendar 
    (weekday varchar(10), 
     date int,
    month varchar(10),
    year int)
    while @fecha_actual <= @fecha_final
     begin
        insert into #temp_calendar
            select                 
                   datename(dw, @fecha_actual), 
                   datepart(day, @fecha_actual), 
                   datename(month, @fecha_actual),                     
                   datepart(year, @fecha_actual)                   
            set @fecha_actual = dateadd(dd, 1, @fecha_actual)                   
     end




    Select  datepart(day,sh.[Order Date]) as Fecha,
            --sh.[Order Date] as Fecha,

            sh.[Responsibility Center],
           (select COUNT ([Unit of Measure Code]) 
            from [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Invoice Line]
            where [Document No_]=sih.[No_]
            and [Unit of Measure Code]='DIA'
            and (charindex('S-HANDS FREE',upper([No_]))<=0)
            and(charindex('GARAN',upper([No_]))<=0)
            and(charindex('DEMO',upper([No_]))<=0))Vendidas,

           (select COUNT ([Unit of Measure Code]) 
            from [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Line] 
                where     [Document No_]=sh.No_ and [Pre Service Start Date]<>'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000' and [Unit of Measure Code]='DIA')Instaladas

                into #temp_Temporal

     from [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Header] sh
                    inner join [Pointer Mexico SA$Customer] c on sh.[Sell-to Customer No_] =c.[No_]
                    inner join [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Invoice Header] sih on sh.[No_]=[Order No_]



     where sih.[Order Date] between '2017/01/01' and '2017/01/30' and sh.[Shortcut Dimension 1 Code] in ('DV10','DV30') 
     --where sih.[Order Date] between @fecha_inicial and @fecha_final and sh.[Shortcut Dimension 1 Code] in ('DV10','DV30') 
      and  ((charindex('DEMO',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0) AND (charindex('RENO',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0) 
      and (charindex('CESI',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0)and      (charindex('GARAN',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0) )
      and sih.[Reason Code]<>'GARANTIAS' and sh.[Tipo de Venta]<>'ACCESORIOS'  
order by Fecha asc



    select Fecha as Date_F,
         [CMEX],         
         [CMTY]

        ,sum(Vendidas) as Sells
--      ,sum(Instaladas) as Installss       
        from #temp_Temporal inner join #temp_calendar on 
                                #temp_calendar.date = #temp_Temporal.Fecha
            pivot(
                  sum(Instaladas) for [Responsibility Center] in ([CMEX],[CMTY])                  
                 ) as s         
        group by Fecha, CMEX, CMTY
        order by Fecha asc


    Date_F  CMEX    CMTY    Sells
4       NULL    0         1
4   0   NULL    5
5   0   NULL    0
5   1   NULL    1
5   3   NULL    3
6   2   NULL    1
9   0   NULL    1
10  0   NULL    0
10  28  NULL    30
11  3   NULL    3
12      NULL    0       2
16  0   NULL    4
```

Este es el resultado al cual quiero llegar:

```
DATE    CMEX_SELLS  CMEX_INSTALL    CMTY_SELLS  CMTY_INSTALL    TOTAL
1            1          1              0            0             2
2            2          5              2            3            12
3            5          5              4            4            18
4           12          5              4            4            25
5           45          4             45           56           150
```

Gracias, ya me apoyaron en mi trabajo. Les comparto una posible solución, por si a alguien le sirve en el futuro. Se utiliza la función "With Transp"
-----SOLUCIÓN POSIBLE.

```
with Transp as (
    select Fecha        
           ,sum(Vendidas) as Total_Vendidas
           ,sum(Instaladas) as Total_Instaladas
           ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMEX' then sum(Vendidas) end as Vendidas_CMEX
           ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMTY' then sum(Vendidas) end as Vendidas_CMTY
           ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMEX' then sum(Instaladas) end as Instaladas_CMEX
           ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMTY' then sum(Instaladas) end as Instaladas_CMTY
           from #temp_Temporal  right join #temp_calendar  on date = Fecha
        group by Fecha , [Responsibility Center] 
) select Fecha
, sum(Vendidas_CMEX) Vendidas_CMEX, sum(Vendidas_CMTY) Vendidas_CMTY
, sum(Instaladas_CMEX) Instaladas_CMEX , sum(Instaladas_CMTY) Instaladas_CMTY
, Sum(Total_Vendidas) Total_Vendidas, sum(Total_Instaladas) Total_Instaladas
From Transp
group by Fecha 
order by Fecha asc
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda, ya me brindaron un poco de ayuda mis compañeros del trabajo. Les envio una posible solución. A ver que les parece.

Comment: Hola Ric_hc, si pudiste encontrar la solución a tu pregunta te recomiendo que la escribas como una respuesta, esto ayuda a tener una mejor base consolidada de preguntas y respuestas

Comment: De hecho esta al final, esta agregada con la función With Transp, estoy también anexando el código, si lo pueden agregar como respuesta o comentario por favor, por que a mí no me permite por la cantidad de caracteres.

Comment: Sí, he visto que ahí está la solución, pero yo me refiero a que la escribas como una respuesta en la sección inferior de la página donde dice **Tu Respuesta**

Comment: Alguien me puede ayudar por favor, una disculpa, no estaba en mi lugar de trabajo. Quiero publicar la respuesta, pero no me permite. Grax

Comment: ¿Te envía algún error?

Comment: Si, no me deja agregarla. Me indica que ya conteste varias preguntas hoy.

Comment: Sí te envía algún error puedes plantear una pregunta en Meta o exponerlo directamente en el chat, siempre ten en cuenta poner los detalles

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53962/discussion-between-ric-hc-and-flxtr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les comparto respuesta a la cual llegué: Se utilizó el `case`, en este caso. Les agrego la solución.

```
with Transp as (
select Fecha        
       ,sum(Vendidas) as Total_Vendidas
       ,sum(Instaladas) as Total_Instaladas
       ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMEX' then sum(Vendidas) end as Vendidas_CMEX
       ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMTY' then sum(Vendidas) end as Vendidas_CMTY
       ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMEX' then sum(Instaladas) end as Instaladas_CMEX
       ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMTY' then sum(Instaladas) end as Instaladas_CMTY
       from #temp_Temporal  right join #temp_calendar  on date = Fecha
    group by Fecha , [Responsibility Center] 
) select Fecha
, sum(Vendidas_CMEX) Vendidas_CMEX, sum(Vendidas_CMTY) Vendidas_CMTY
, sum(Instaladas_CMEX) Instaladas_CMEX , sum(Instaladas_CMTY) Instaladas_CMTY
, Sum(Total_Vendidas) Total_Vendidas, sum(Total_Instaladas) Total_Instaladas
From Transp
group by Fecha 
order by Fecha asc
```